# jQuery Validation - Hide error message and don't submit the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validate for a form.

I have a field that is `required`, but I don't want to display any error message for the field. I just want the form submission to be blocked.

I have tried setting the element error message to this:

```
messages: {
    required: "" 
}
```

However, due to default validation format that I don't have access to (it is a common file that I cannot change), I still see a background/box with a blank error message.

Is there a way to hide the rendering of the error message for a specific element, while still preventing the form submission?

Comment: Show your code.  Where is the HTML markup?  Where is the call to `.validate()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"Is there a way to hide the rendering of the error message for a specific element, while still preventing the form submission?"*

See [the `errorPlacement` callback function](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement), which controls where messages are placed.

Use a conditional so that you `return false` on the specific element, which effectively prevents a message from being placed, while allowing the default message placement on the rest.

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        ....
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.attr('name') == 'myName') {
            return false;  // no message placement
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element); // default message placement
        }
    }
});
```

**[DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/3cndvv3o/](http://jsfiddle.net/3cndvv3o/)**